# Node delete folder starting with period

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't seem to get node to delete a folder if it happens to start with a period. For example say I have a ".TestDir" directory. I would anticipate the following should delete it:

```
await fs.promises.rm('.TestDir', {
    recursive: true,
    force: true,
});
```

Instead I keep getting the following error:

`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Error`

If I remove the period from the directory name then it works exactly as I expect, unfortunately I don't have control of the directory name because it is generated by another system. Can anyone tell me what I am missing here? I am running Node v16.16.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You can make it work by appending a slash to the path as follows:

```
await fs.promises.rm('/.TestDir', {
    recursive: true,
    force: true,
});
```